# Can I add an ActionListener to a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, actionlistener

I am creating a swing program which basically has a lot of buttons, and I was thinking that instead of adding the listener individually to each button, if I could add the listener to the `JPanel` instead, and read the events using `.getSource()` function, things would be a whole lot easier? Is it possible?

Comment: Do all the buttons have the same functionality? If they are the same then create a single `ActionListener` and do as @ivanovic said (+1 to him). If they are not the same you may be interested in [Anonymous Listeners](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/events/anonymous_listener.html) which you can add to individual buttons. I would shy away from a single `ActionListener` and *if checks* for which button is pressed. But if you must than rather than do as @mKorbel suggested using [`xxxActionCommand`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/GetandsetActionCommand.htm) (+1 to him)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a listener to a component doesn't mean that you are also adding that listener to the internal components. Instead, think of using groups of buttons (e.g. a button array)
and add the listener to all buttons with one iteration.

```
for(JButton button : buttonsArray)
    button.addActionListener(yourActionListener);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am creating a swing program which basically has a lot of buttons,
>   and I was thinking that instead of adding the listener individually to
>   each button, if I could add the listener to the JPanel instead, and
>   read the events using .getSource() function, things would be a whole
>   lot easier? Is it possible?

not possible to add `ActionListener`, only `MouseListener` can do that, but not correct way for `JButton`

depends of your code, you have to add ActionListener to every JButtons and to determinte which one is pressed by

- `put/getClientProperty`
- `ActionCommand`
- programatically loop instide arrays of `JButtons` and to compare event and `JButton`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not, take a look on [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)

If all your buttons have the same listener  behavior, add them to `ArrayList<JButton>` and in loop add the same instance of `ActionListener`